# How to set the directory when saving file with filewriter in java?

Tags: java, directory, save, filewriter

Hi I'm using NetBeans for more easy-to-use GUI.

I'm trying to save a txt file which I get the name from the user, using the FileWriter, (not using serializable)

I think I could set the saving location of the file using the Serializable (I'm not sure)

but, my code kinda looks dirty if I use Serializable and it causes some error. (I use 2 classes)

**Anyway, Is there a way to set the directory when saving the txt file with the FileWriter?**

This is my code, for saving files.

```
    public boolean save() {
    try {
        File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\JSK\\Desktop\\BOARD\\data");

        String str = Title_field.getText() + ".txt";
        CheckFile(str);
        CheckCbox();
        area.append("\n Written at :" + date_format.format(now.getTime()));
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(str);
        fw.write(area.getText());
        fw.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Successfully Written");
        this.setVisible(false);
        Title_field.setEditable(false);
        area.setEditable(false);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You Must Create A File First!", "File Missing", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "I/O ERROR", "Failed to save the file", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } catch (FileExistException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "File Already Exists, Please Change the title", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        area.setText("");
        return false;
    } catch (CheckboxSelectionException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You must select at least one location", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        Title_field.setText("");
        area.setText("");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**dir means the directory where I want to save it, but it actually saves inside C:\Users\JSK\Desktop\BOARD**

Comment: Create an outputstream valid instance http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of this line:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(str);
```

Try this:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File(dir, str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the directory you want to create and use mkdir() method to create the directory then, mention that created directory inside the FileWriter. This will create your directory inside the directory of your project.

```
try {
    final File dir = new File("data");
    if (!dir.exists()) {
       if (!dir.mkdir()) {
          System.out.println("Folder Not Found!!!");
          System.exit(0);
       } else {
         FileWriter file = new FileWriter(new File(dir, "logs.txt"));
         PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
         pw.printf("Logs for Hello World");
            }
        } else {
            FileWriter file = new FileWriter(new File(dir, "logs.txt"));
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
            pw.printf("Logs for Hello World");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```